# Fix formatting issue with Gmail on Firefox

Tags: gmail, firefox

On two computers now, I have a strange recurring visual formatting bug when accessing Gmail using Firefox. One email, usually towards the bottom of the page, has a blue block over the date. I have reloaded multiple times and cleared out the gmail cookies. I have even cleared out the entire cache, but the problem persists. Any ideas what is causing this?

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem, using both normal and priority inboxes, are there any sepcial settings you have enabled? Are you using the latest version of FF?

Comment: thanks Kyle, it was indeed a "special setting" - I had the google calendar gadget turned on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical, no sooner do I post the issue, than I work out what was causing it. It was the Google Calendar gadget from the Google Labs settings page. The badly formatted email was in line with the top of the gadget.